# NSMutableDictionary - EXC BAD ACCESS - simultaneous read/write

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsmutablearray, core-foundation

I was hoping for some help with my app.

I have a set up where multiple threads access a shared `NSMutableDictionary` owned by a singleton class. The threads access the dictionary in response to downloading JSON and processing it. The singleton class is basically preventing duplication of some downloaded objects which have an unique id number.

ie.

```
    //NSURLConnection calls:
    [[Singleton sharedInstance] processJSON:data];

@interface Singleton
+ (Singleton) sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *store;
@end

@implementation

-(void) processJSON:(NSData*)data {
   ...
   someCustomClass *potentialEntry = [someCustomClass parse:data];
   ...
   if(![self entryExists:potentialEntry.stringId])
        [self addNewEntry:potentialEntry]; 
   ...
  }

-(void) entryExists:(NSString*)objectId {
    if(self.store[objectId])
     return true;
    else return false;
  }

 -(void) addEntry:(someCustomClass *object) {
    self.store[object.stringId] = object;
  }
```

There can be as many as 5-10 threads at a time calling processJSON at once.

Not immediately but after a few minutes of running (quicker on the iPhone than on the simulator) I get the dreaded EXC BAD ACCESS.

I don't confess to know how `NSMutableDictionary` works but I would guess that there's some kind of hash table in the background which needs to be updated when assigning objects and read when accessing objects. Therefore, if threads were to instantaneously read/write to a dictionary, this error could occur - may be because an object has moved in memory?

Im hoping that someone with more knowledge on the subject could enlighten me!

As for solutions I was thinking of the singleton class having an `NSOperationQueue` with a maximum concurrent operation number of 1 and then using `operationWithBlock:` whenever I want to access the `NSDictionary`. The only problem is that it makes calling `processJSON` an asynchronous function and I can't return the created object straight away; I'd have to use a block and that would be a bit messier. Is there any way of using `@synchronize`? Would that work well?

Comment: "Mutable objects are generally not thread-safe. To use mutable objects in a threaded application, the application must synchronize access to them using locks. (For more information, see “Atomic Operations”). In general, the collection classes (for example, NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary) are not thread-safe when mutations are concerned. That is, if one or more threads are changing the same array, problems can occur. You must lock around spots where reads and writes occur to assure thread safety."

Comment: (That's from the [MAC version](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) of the docs but should be applicable to iOS.)

Comment: In particular, I'd draw your attention to the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of that doc that Hot Licks points you to. One of those locking mechanisms, or the use of a dedicated serial queue, can help you achieve thread safety.

Comment: By the way, I think your intuition regarding the serial operation queue is promising, though frequently people will use a serial dispatch queue for this (so you can call `dispatch_sync` from any queue to your dictionary's serial queue), achieving both a controlled mechanism for interacting with it as well as synchronous operations. Or,  if using operation queues, you can use `waitUntilFinished` when background operations queues want to make your operations submitted to your serial queue synchronous.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. I had a look at the article and I think the solution lies with GCD. I really should explore the API a bit more! dispatch_sync could be used for reads and dispatch_barrier_async for writes. That way I could handle the part where I check if an object exists synchronously and hand the new object back to the caller while its written into the dictionary at some point shortly after.

Comment: @Vazzyb Often you don't even need `dispatch_barrier_async`, but rather a `dispatch_async` will be sufficient. Anyway, the [GCD documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and the [dispatch queue discussion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) in the _Concurrency Programming Guide_ should provide quite a bit of information.

Comment: The same doc in the iOS library: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

Comment: Unless specifically documented otherwise, there is no guarantee that read operations will be concurrency safe.

Comment: bbum: that sounds like a good docs bug to file if it's not documented :) the reader/writer pattern is valuable enough that people should know if they can use it or not

Comment: I changed over to using GCD and dispatch_snyc/dispatch_barrier_async - made all the difference; no more errors and very fast. And since I encapsulated it in an object im using a custom mutable array throughout my project with great success! Just wondering which answer I should accept (since I didn't use the sync block technique...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd draw your attention to the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the iOS rendition of the *Threading Programming Guide* that Hot Licks pointed you to. One of those locking mechanisms, or the use of a dedicated serial queue, can help you achieve thread safety.

Your intuition regarding the serial operation queue is promising, though frequently people will use a serial dispatch queue for this (e.g., so you can call `dispatch_sync` from any queue to your dictionary's serial queue), achieving both a controlled mechanism for interacting with it as well as synchronous operations. Or, even better, you can use a custom concurrent queue (not a global queue), and perform reads via `dispatch_sync` and perform writes via `dispatch_barrier_async`, achieving an efficient reader/writer scheme (as discussed in [WWDC 2011 - Mastering GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=210) or [WWDC 2012 - Asynchronous Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712)).

The [Eliminating Lock-Based Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) section of the *Concurrency Programming Guide* outlines some of the rationale for using a serial queue for synchronization versus the traditional locking techniques.

The [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and the [dispatch queue discussion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide* should provide quite a bit of information.

Comment: Just so its documented in the answer: I ended up using GCD. It appears that using a concurrent queue with dispatch_sync for reads and dispatch_barrier_async for writes is a great way to work with an NSMutableDictionary in a multithreaded app.

Comment: @Vazzyb Agreed (as long as that concurrent queue is not a global queue, but rather is one you create with `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`). You don't want barriers on global queues, obviously. (I know you know that, but I only add this caveat for future readers.)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to just put all off the code that accesses the dict in an @synchronized block.

serial operation queues are great, but sounds like overkill to me for this, as you aren't guarding a whole ecosystem of data, just one structure..

Comment: dispatch queues are barely any more code and a good bit faster

Comment: it depends on the scenario... but generally I agree... for protecting one data structure, it seems less obfuscated to just @syncronized(theDict)..